# How can I make sure that a method of class can be called from a specific class only?

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class A
{
    private void MethodA(){}
}

public class B
{
    private void MethodB() { }
}

public class C
{
    private void MethodC() { }
}
```

I want to make sure that `MethodA` can be called only from `MethodB`. Other method can never call `MethodA`.

Comment: Why don't you move class C into another assembly and make MethodA internal?

Comment: are all your methods private ? if yes, they can never be called from anywhere outside.

Comment: @chanchal-zoarder see my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `MethodA` protected and use inheritance like this:

```
public class A
{
    protected void MethodA()
    {
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    private void MethodB()
    {
        //MethodA is accessible just here
    }
}

public class C
{
    private void MethodC()
    {
        //MethodA is not accessible here
    }
}
```

But if you don't want to use inheritance and want all the classes in the **same assembly** you could only nest class `B` within class `A` and keep `MethodA` private. Like this:

```
public class A
{
    private void MethodA()
    {
    }
    public class B
    {
        private void MethodB()
        {
            A a = new A();
            a.MethodA();
        }
    }
}

public class C
{
    private void MethodC()
    {
        //MethodA is not accessible here
    }
}

public class D : A
{
    private void MethodC()
    {
        //MethodA is not accessible here
    }
}
```

Comment: If class C Inherit A, MethodA can be called inside MethodC

Comment: @ChanchalZoarder...One another approach maybe you want to nest class `B` within class `A` if you don't want to use inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

I note that S.Akbari's answer, though good, does not exactly meet your requirement. You said that you wanted `MethodA` to be callable only within `B`, but in their answer, `MethodA` is callable within `A`.

The solution to the problem you actually posed is to invert the nesting:

```
class B
{
  private class A
  {
    public void MethodA() { }
  }
}
```

Now `MethodA` can only be called from within `B`.

But the question is bizarre. If you have a method that can only be called from `B` then why is it not a member of `B`?